# Syntax error: Unclosed string literal at [10:5]

Tags: json, parsing, google-bigquery

```
SELECT type, key
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM
  js(
    (SELECT json, type FROM arboreal-vision-339901.take_home.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours
    ),
    -- Input columns.
    json, type,
    -- Output schema.
    "[{name: 'key', type:'string'},     -- error here
     {name: 'type', type:'string'}]",
     -- The function.
     "function(r, emit) { 
      x=JSON.parse(r.json)
      Object.keys(x).forEach(function(entry) {
        emit({key:entry, type:r.type,});
      });     
    }"
  )
)
LIMIT 10
```

can't understand why there's an error with `"[{name: 'key', type:'string'}`

could anyone please help me solve this. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi lines you need to use multi quotation marks i.e `”””` or `’’’` at the beginning and end of the string. For more information you can refer to the  [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#literals) .

You can try this below query:

```
SELECT type, key
FROM (
 SELECT * FROM
 js(
   (SELECT json, type FROM arboreal-vision-339901.take_home.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours
   ),
   -- Input columns.
   json, type,
   -- Output schema.
   """[{name: 'key', type:'string'},     -- error here
    {name: 'type', type:'string'}]""",
    -- The function.
    """function(r, emit) {
     x=JSON.parse(r.json)
     Object.keys(x).forEach(function(entry) {
       emit({key:entry, type:r.type,});
     });    
   }"""
 )
)
LIMIT 10
```